# Using configure flags in Makefile

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I am working on a project that requires the targets in `Makefile.am` change with the flags passed during `./configure`.

To be more specific, if `./configure` is invoked with the `--enable-threads` option, then the check target for make should also execute the relevant tests. So in `Makefile.am` I would like to be able to identify if configure was called with `--enable-threads` or no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be easiest to use an [automake conditional](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Conditional-Sources.html). Just set an `AM_CONDITIONAL` in `configure.ac` using the results of the `AC_ARG_ENABLE(threads,...)`.  I'm assuming there's at least one variable set there that you could use to set the `AM_CONDITIONAL`.  Then in `Makefile.am` add the tests inside the conditional to the check target.